# ¿Donde debo subir mis archivos en un servidor Apache?

Tags: webservice, apache, tomcat

Tengo un servidor ,al cual le voy a realizar una serie de cambios, tiene dos directorios, /tomcat y /www.

En la carpeta **/www se encuentra una aplicación PHP** que es la que visualiza el cliente.

En la carpeta **/tomcat se encuentra un Proyecto Web hecho en Java**, que también tiene visualización para el cliente pero que se va a borrar.

No se muy bien la diferencia entre estas dos carpetas y que se debe subir a cada una.

Yo hice la aplicación web PHP y ahora queremos borrar la web antigua(la subida a /tomcat) pero hay una aplicación de escritorio hecha en C# que trabaja con unos archivos subidos a la ruta de tomcat, he probado a realizar lo mismo en php y subirlo en la carpeta /www y sigue funcionando correctamente, pero no se si esto es correcto sobre todo en temas de seguridad.
El caso es que no se si esto es correcto  y sobre todo si es seguro.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La carpeta `www` es la raíz de los documentos públicos. Dentro de ella, en teoría, todo es accesible para los usuarios en general. Por encima de la misma, se consideran archivos y carpetas del servidor.

Otros nombres que he visto para la carpeta `www`, pero con fines similares son `htdocs`, `public_html`, `WWWroot`